# Changing background color of a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with this code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
switch(item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.menu_green:
          if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
          else item.setChecked(true);
          mainLayout.setBackgroundColor.(Color.GREEN);
                return true;
      default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

I am trying to change the background color when the option is selected inside the menuItem. The menuItem Green is only displayed when I have the fragment button turned on. Is this the correct place to try and change the background? Inside the fragment the mainLayout is red-underlined.

```
Activity_Main.XML
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Frag1.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_green"
        android:title="Green"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: You would need to share your xml file as we don't know what mainLayout is. For all we know there is a child layout element inside of it that is match parent

Comment: I had the code inside the frag.java and not in the java.main. After moving it to java.main it ran correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this Code For changing fragment background color

```
case R.id.menu_green:
          if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
          else item.setChecked(true);
         fragment.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                return true;
```

Comment: I update my answer. now try it and let me know if it helps you